# JOINS AND SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Question -**
Display customer Id, name, and total number of orders, for orders handled by salesman Marshall, but only if customer name begins on General or ends on Electric. Exclude customers who placed a single order, but include customers without orders as well. Sort the result based on the total number of orders descending and then by name ascending.
Do not use LIKE operator and do not join 3 tables.

**Questions output**

[image: Question output]

**Current Query**

```
SELECT c.customer_id, 
       c.name, 
       Count(o.order_id) "# of Orders" 
FROM   customers c 
       left join orders o 
              ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id 
WHERE  Substr(c.name, 1, 7) = 'General' 
        OR Substr(c.name, -8) = 'Electric' 
           AND o.order_id IN (SELECT o.order_id
                              FROM   orders o, 
                                     order_items oi 
                              WHERE  o.order_id = oi.order_id 
                                     AND o.salesman_id = (SELECT employee_id 
                                                           FROM   employees 
                                                           WHERE 
                                         last_name = 'Marshall') 
                              GROUP  BY o.order_id 
                              HAVING Count(customer_id) > 1) 
GROUP  BY c.customer_id, 
          c.name;
```

[image: Current Output]

**Database -**

[image: Database 1/2]
[image: Database 2/2]

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really contrived assignment... Here is one option:

```
select c.customer_id, c.customer_name, count(o.orderid) cnt
from customers c
left join orders o 
    on  o.customer_id = c.customer_id
    and (select last_name from employee e where e.employee_id = o.salesman_id) = 'Marshall'
where substr(c.name, 1, 7) = 'General' or substr(c.name, -8) = 'Electric'
group by c.customer_id, c.customer_name
having count(o.orderid) <> 1
```

The base idea is a `left join`. The `where` clause filters on the customer name - without `like`: you had that already.

To filter on the salesman name without an additional join, we use a correlated subquery in the `on` clause of the `left join`. There is no need to bring `order_items`, nor to select again from `orders` here.

Finally, the filtering on the order counts goes to the `having` clause.